# What does setDefaultMaxPerRoute and setMaxTotal mean in HttpClient?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient in one of my project. I am also using `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` along with my HttpClient as well.

I am confuse what are these properties mean. I tried going through documentation in the code but I don't see any  documentation around these variables so was not able to understand.

- setMaxTotal
- setDefaultMaxPerRoute
- setConnectTimeout
- setSocketTimeout
- setConnectionRequestTimeout
- setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled

Below is how I am using in my code:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000).setSocketTimeout(5 * 1000)
        .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(false).build();
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
poolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);

CloseableHttpClient httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .build();
```

Can anyone explain me these properties so that I can understand and decide what values I should put in there. Also, are there any other properties that I should use apart from as shown above to get better performance?

I am using http-client 4.3.1

Comment: Well, how this can be too broad. There should be single line answer for what I am asking?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some parameters are explained at http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/preference-api.html

Others must be gleaned from the source.

- **setMaxTotal**

The maximum number of connections allowed across all routes.

- **setDefaultMaxPerRoute**

The maximum number of connections allowed for a route that has not been specified otherwise by a call to setMaxPerRoute.  Use setMaxPerRoute when you know the route ahead of time and setDefaultMaxPerRoute when you do not.

- **setConnectTimeout**

How long to wait for a connection to be established with the remote server before throwing a timeout exception.

- **setSocketTimeout**

How long to wait for the server to respond to various calls before throwing a timeout exception.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT for details.

- **setConnectionRequestTimeout**

How long to wait when trying to checkout a connection from the connection pool before throwing an exception (the connection pool won't return immediately if, for example, all the connections are checked out).

- **setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled**

Can be disabled for a slight performance improvement at the cost of potential IOExceptions.  See http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Stale_connection_check

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood on all points leaving `setDefaultMaxPerRoute`. I am only confuse on `routes` part. What does route mean here?

Comment: It is an HttpRoute instance, defined in more detail on http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/routing/HttpRoute.html which specifies a hostname or address.  This could be used, for example, when you know that a certain host would benefit from a large number of connections but you don't want to allow a large number of connections to all other hosts.

Comment: when the pool is [total available: 5; route allocated: 50 of 50; total allocated: 18 of 100] starts getting timeout, it has CloseableHttpClient, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with MaxTotal 100, DefaultMaxPerRoute 50 configured, also a ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy with 20 secs, what can be the error ?